# Counting words separated by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, cpu-word, counter

My counter function looks like that

```
function count() {
    var value =  ids.val();
    return (value == '') ? 0 : value.replace(/\s,?|,$/g, '').split(',').length;
}
```

Then checking for returned value and posting data via ajax

```
if(count() === 10){   
    ajaxPost();     
    $(ids).val('');
}
```

I set interval to use this function. Noting that, tried all other function like change(),paste().. the only way that worked with my scanner device is, to set interval.

The problem is, when i type 9 numbers, like 1...9 and then want to type 10, when I press 1 to write 10 right after 9, it directly posts data. doesn't wait for ",". How can I modify it to wait for "," after last (in this case 10th) word?

Comment: can you kindly describe step by step the procedure and what you want done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the key pressed and see if it is a comma, then only run your code after it is known that the last key entered was a comma:

```
$(ids).on('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.which == 188) {
        if (count(this.value) === 10) {
            ajaxPost();     
            ids.value = '';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I already told that, it's not keyboard, it's scanner device (barcode scanner). So keyup doesn't work. Only way is to set interval

Answer (score 1):

10 words with a trailing comma give you 10 commas, consequently, 11 elements in the `split` result array (the last element will be empty if comma is the last character of the input). Check it like `if (count() === 11)...`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
var count = function(str){
  var matches = str.match(/.*?,/g);
  return (matches == null)? 0 : matches.length;
};
```

Also you can probably use the keyup or keydown methods to catch this event rather than using a setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood your question completely, but...

You want to wait for a last "," to make sure that all numbers were typed by your scanner? Or you need to get that 10 but the interval occurs just before the scanner finished writing it?

If it is the second case, I recommend you to restart the interval at every keyPressed event. Doing that, you'll give some time just after the key was pressed to wait in case any other key is pressed too.

So, you'll have something like this:

```
var lastInterval = null
$(ids).keyPress(function() {
    if(lastInterval != null)
        clearTimeout(lastInterval)
    lastInterval = setInterval(function() {
        // ... your code here
    }, 1000)
})
```

Is this clear? Hope it helps :)

--- EDIT

Ok, it's weird that a barcode scanner doesn't trigger `keyPress` events, but taking this as a premise, you could check for changes in the string, and when the string didn't change in N cycles, you trigger your code.

In this example, you'll be sure that the string remained equal **at least** 1000 ms (between 1000ms and 1999ms).

```
var lastString = ""
setInterval(function() {
    if(lastString == $(ids).val()) { // So, if the value remains the same for 2 cycles, the second one your code will be evaluated
        // ... your code here
    }
    lastString = $(ids).val()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: I already told that, it's not keyboard, it's scanner device (barcode scanner). So keyup doesn't work. Only way is to set interval

Comment: edited :) hope it helps now. Anyway, check why the codebar scanner doesn't fire the proper event. Is it connected by serial/usb or as a keyboard attach?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would put this code into a keypress handler.  That way it would only be invoked when you type new characters.  To prevent it from running the check too often, use [_.debounce](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce).  Finally, as Andrew mentioned, ",,,,,,,,,,".split(',').length == 11.  It appears that you are sabotaging yourself with that regular expression that looks for an optional final comma.

Comment: I already told that, it's not keyboard, it's scanner device (barcode scanner). So keyup doesn't work. Only way is to set interval